# SDK DatePicker IsTabStop Ignored

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, user-interface, datepicker

Standard (SL4) SDK [DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278067%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) doesn't seem to recognize when I set the `IsTabStop="False"` on it. I'm aware there's an embedded `TextBox` for the input as `System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:DatePickerTextBox` which if you drill down to its template is already set as `IsTabStop="False"` which is confusing?

The parent template has a `Setter` declaring the template as `IsTabStop="False"` so my question is? Why/how would it be ignored?

I tried `TemplateBinding` to `IsTabStop` on the `System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:DatePickerTextBox` in the template which works...except for the fact that when you try to tab backwards via <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> it won't tab in reverse?

So I'm a bit confused... I even tried to set it via a `Style` `TargetType` declaration on the instance via the `DatePicker.Resources` and can't seem to get to the bugger.

Has anyone ran into this before? I'm surprised as hell that I haven't before and would love to know a reason and/or a workaround for it. Or if it's perhaps something unique to this scenario. Thanks!

PS - Only other workarounds I've seen were for WPF and don't pertain to this issue.

Comment: what do you mean by ctrl + tab won't shift in reverse? Did you mean shift + tab?

Comment: Good catch, ya sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test, I created a new SL 5 Project (sorry, don't have 4 installed) and dropped a TextBox, Two DatePickers, and another TextBox so I could see the tab action.

I then set IsTabStop to False on the first DatePicker, and like you say, it is ignored.

I then made a copy of the template, found the DatePickerTextBox and added IsTabStop="False" and ran it again.

It then skipped the DatePicker when tabbing forward or backwards.  So this should work for you.

```
<Primitives:DatePickerTextBox x:Name="TextBox"
                                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                      IsTabStop="False"
                                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" />
```

The IsTabStop is ignored by the default template simply because there is code missing in the SDK that should bind it to the DatePickerTextBox.

Greg

Comment: I think this is what I tried but I bound it to the template via `IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"` except then it would respect the forward tab order, but not the reverse, it won't reverse tab to the DatePicker once it's been tabbed past via Shift+Tab which is no bueno also. So I'll try this again though and try to see the outcome. Thanks either way!

Comment: I just added the template binding, and it does work for me with tabbing past, and then Shift+tab to reverse tab. But in any case, your welcome! Greg

Comment: well shoot I'll have to look into more than, hopefully its not just another downfall between SL4 vs SL5 I keep running into. :/ Either way it's frustrating lol

Comment: Had to do some finesse in the template but got it working, counted as correct answer since I hate leaving stuff as unanswered and ya went through the trouble of testing even if SL5, thanks